# Installed drivers and Windows 7 still cannot detect HP 2011x monitor

Tags: windows-7, drivers, multiple-monitors

I have 2 monitors and each are plugged into a dvi port on my videocard.

HP 2011x
HP 20xi

I downloaded and installed each driver from the HP website, restarted, same issue. Then I downloaded the HP Driver Assistant which just redownloaded the above 2 updates.

Windows 7 also detected an optional update and I installed that too (which for some reason cannot be uninstalled via Programs and Features - View installed updates)

HP - Display - HP Pavilion 20xi IPS LED Backlit Monitor

The monitors are stuck mirroring each other and when I try to detect the monitors, only the HP 20xi will appear and one other thing that's strange is that Windows thinks the monitor is hooked up using a VGA port.

HP Pavilion 20xi IPS LED Backlit Monitor on Standard VGA Graphics Adapter

Also the monitors can both be detected on Linux Mint.

Comment: Do you have the proper driver installed for your videocard, or is it listed as "Standard VGA Graphics adapter"?

Comment: You are completely correct. I forgot to install the r9 270's drivers. It's installed and working. Feel free to put that comment into a response and I'll select that as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Video Card or Graphics Adapter is listed in the device manager as "Standard VGA Graphics Adapter" then you are running it on Windows Standard Drivers. That might result in only one of the available ports on your Video Card being accessible or as in your case both putting out the same signal. Install the Drivers from the Manufacturer and you will be able to use all your ports beside other benefits.